# RXswift, repeat observable until complete

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am trying to upload firmware to a BLE device. Therefore I push some data, wait for an acknowledgment and then push some more, and so on.
But I am struggling with repeating the observer until the observer returns complete.

This is the observer, so if there are no more packets to be sent, it should complete and stop repeating.

```
let transferImage = Observable<Void>.create { (obs) -> Disposable in
        guard let nextPacket = dataSendingTracker.getNextPacket() else {
            obs.onCompleted()
            return Disposables.create()
        }

        return self.instrument()
            .flatMap{ $0.sendFWpacket(packet: nextPacket) }
            .subscribe(onNext: { () in
                obs.onNext(())
            }, onError: { (error) in
                obs.onError(error)
            })
    }
```

Any suggestion on how I can achieve this?

Comment: your `self.instrument()` is an observable, why do you need to create new observable `transferImage`? and why dont you make your `dataSendingTracker` as an observable also?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this but I consider this ugly way around.... not Rx Solution

transferImage.takeWhile will stop when getNextPacket returns nil or this case Integer smaller than zero..

```
     func test() {
    let transferImage = Observable<Int>.create { (obs) -> Disposable in
        if let nextPacket = self.getNextPacket() {
            obs.onNext(nextPacket)

        } else{
            obs.onNext(-1)
            obs.onCompleted()

        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }

    transferImage.takeWhile{$0 > 0}.subscribe(onNext: { nextPacket in
        print(nextPacket)
        let completed = self.sendFWpacket()
        if !completed {
            self.test()
        }

    }, onError: { error in
        print(error)
    }, onCompleted: {
        print("onCompleted")
    }) {
        print("disposed")
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

}

func sendFWpacket()-> Bool {
    return false
}

func getNextPacket() ->  Int? {
    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function that writes a block of data like this test function:

```
func writeDataBlock(offset: Int, blockSize: Int) -> Observable<Int> {
    let writtenBytesCount = min(Int(arc4random_uniform(5) + 5), blockSize)
    return Observable<Int>.just(writtenBytesCount)
}
```

*In reality this function would also use some data buffer and try to push a block of a given size from that data at a given offset, and return the number of bytes written when done. Here you could use your logic from `transferImage`.*

Then the complete transfer function could be written using recursion like so:

```
func writeAllDataRec(offset: Int, totalSize: Int, observer: AnyObserver<String>) {
    guard offset < totalSize else {
        observer.onNext("writeAllData completed")
        observer.onCompleted()
        return
    }

    var subscriber: Disposable?
    let blockSize = min(10, totalSize - offset)
    subscriber = writeDataBlock(offset: offset, blockSize: blockSize).subscribe { ev in
        switch ev {
        case let .next(writtenBytesCount):
            debugPrint("writeNextBlock from offset: \(offset); writtenBytesCount = \(writtenBytesCount)")
            let newOffset = offset + writtenBytesCount
            writeAllDataRec(offset: newOffset, totalSize: totalSize, observer: observer)
        case .completed:
            subscriber?.dispose()
            //debugPrint("writeAllData block completed")
        case let .error(err):
            subscriber?.dispose()
            observer.onError(err)
            observer.onCompleted()
        }
    }
}

func writeAllData(totalSize: Int) -> Observable<String> {
    return Observable<String>.create { (observer) -> Disposable in
        writeAllDataRec(offset: 0, totalSize: totalSize, observer: observer)
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

This could be tested like so:

```
var subscriber: Disposable?
...
    self.subscriber = writeAllData(totalSize: 100).subscribe(onNext: { (message) in
        print("\(message)")
    })
```

In this solution I assume that your next block of data depends on how much of the data was written previously and that there's no shared global state.

This could be simplified a lot with the logic of [RxJS expand](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/expand.md), but unfortunately this function is not present in RxSwift (4.1.2).